# Fastlane task fails when building Application Bundle (AAB) on MacOS Catalina Android Studio 4.1

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, flutter, fastlane

Fastlane is unable to locate the JRE installed with Android Studio when building my Android application bundle (AAB) and it presents the following error:

```
No Java runtime present, requesting install
```

Answer (score 1):

Update Zshell Profile to include the Android Studio JRE path in JAVA_HOME

Steps:

1. Open a terminal window or navigate to android studio terminal
2. Run the command `java -version` and confirm Java cannot be found
3. `vi ~/.zshrc`
4. `i` to switch to INSERT mode
5. Add the following export line below the flutter export path (or the last line of your file)
6. `export JAVA_HOME=/Applications/Android\ Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home`
7. Hit **esc** to exit INSERT mode
8. Type :wq
9. Hit **return** to write to the file and quit VI
10. Close and reopen your terminal window
11. Run the command `java -version` and confirm Java is now successfully detected